# Remove desktop folder which is on the desktop and contains everything on the desktop

Tags: folders, desktop

I don't how this happend, but I feel like my machine is experiencing a *Being John Malkovich* syndrome.

There is a folder on my Desktop called Desktop which contains all the other folders on my Desktop. I want to get rid of this folder, but not the contents of my desktop.

Any advice?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the folder. Select All. Copy. Click on the Desktop. Paste. Delete the folder.

Comment: Select then Drag is probably easier and less error prone.

Comment: I miss targets too often when dragging. Particular with the three-finger drag gesture on my MacBook Air. But to each his own...

Comment: You miss the **desktop**? you might want to get that checked out :)

Comment: Seriously, yes -- sometimes I hit an open window or the Dock instead.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to check using the Terminal command ls -ld for whether you have a directory containing a soft symlink to itself.  If so, you can just delete the symlink.